# Regex for at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase, one number OR special character

Tags: regex

The password validation requirements for my input field are as follows: "Password should contain at least one uppercase, one lowercase letter, one number *OR* special character".

This is the regex for 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 number AND one special character

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]
```

Comment: Are you asking us to explain your own password requirements, or the regex?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a regex like this:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d$@$!%*?&]).*$
```

In `[\d$@$!%*?&]` you have *at least one number OR one special character*.

Comment: I think he is wanting at least 1 number AND 1 special character.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one help you

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{8,8})
```

Password must be 8 characters including 1 uppercase letter, 1 special character, alphanumeric characters